# Conditional SetEnv after PassEnv

Tags: apache2

I need to force `PERL5OPT` env variable to `-d` in any case when `INSTANCE_MODE` env variable eq `test`.

Something like this:

```
PassEnv PERL5OPT
PassEnv INSTANCE_MODE
SetEnvIf INSTANCE_MODE test PERL5OPT=-d
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Is it possible at all and what is the right syntax ?

What syntax I've tried also:

```
SetEnvIf %{INSTANCE_MODE} "test" PERL5OPT=-d NO
SetEnvIf %{ENV:INSTANCE_MODE} "test" PERL5OPT=-d NO
SetEnvIfExpr "env('INSTANCE_MODE') == 'test'" PERL5OPT=-d
SetEnvIfExpr "osenv('INSTANCE_MODE') == 'test'" PERL5OPT=-d
SetEnvIfExpr "%{INSTANCE_MODE} == 'test'" PERL5OPT=-d # error: Variable 'INSTANCE_MODE' does not exist
SetEnvIfExpr "env('INSTANCE_MODE') == 'test'" PERL5OPT=-d
```

`$httpd -v` : `Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [If](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if) directive is probably more appropriate, try:

```
<If "osenv('INSTANCE_MODE') == 'test'">
    SetEnv PERL5OPT "-d"
</If>
```